# FB IDB usage in test automation

Tags: ios, automation, appium, fb-idb

I could set up to run fb-idb cli commands with iOS simulator, also build was succeeded for idb_companion tool. Proper documentations are found for invoking commands for device.
Now I am looking how these commands can be implemented using python. Any wrapper or lib for acheiving this ? Can we use these idb commands from python program, any thoughts ? Also Appium lists idb as an optional dependency. Any documentation or guide to explore idb using Appium ?

Comment: I found this URL - https://fbidb.io/. Is there way to use idb in Appium Inspector?

Answer (score 0):

We can use idb command from python by taking ssh to Mac in which the iOS device is connected. you can use the path /usr/local/bin/ to execute idb commands.